# HTML to JSX REACT: addEventListener to onClick

Tags: reactjs, jsx, addeventlistener

This needs to be changed from HTML to JSX. I also need help making this have "onClick" instead of the addEventListeners. Trying to put this into React, and it is not liking the addEventListeners whatsoever. It is a modal login from BULMA. Here is the code:
Please paste the solution with a description so I know how you changed it.

```
<body> 
<div class='container'> 
   <div class='columns is-mobile is-centered'> 
   <div class='column is-4'> 
       <div class='has-text-centered'> 
       <button class="button is-primary"
               id='btn'> 
           Login form modal 
       </button> 
       </div> 
       <div class="modal"> 
       <div class="modal-background"></div> 
       <div class="modal-content"> 
           <div class="box"> 
           <div> 
               <h1 class='title has-text-centered'> 
               Login 
               </h1> 
           </div> 
           <form action='#' method='post'> 
               <div class='field'> 
               <label class='label'
                       id='username'> 
                   Username 
               </label> 
               <div class='control has-icons-left'> 
                   <input class='input'
                       type='text'
                       for='username'
                       placeholder='Username'> 
                   <span class="icon is-small is-left"> 
                   <i class="fas fa-user"></i> 
                   </span> 
               </div> 
               </div> 

               <div class='field'> 
               <label class='label'
                       id='password'> 
                   Password 
               </label> 
               <div class='control has-icons-left'> 
                   <input class='input'
                       type='password'
                       for='password'
                       placeholder='Password'> 
                   <span class="icon is-small is-left"> 
                   <i class="fas fa-lock"></i> 
                   </span> 
               </div> 

               <div class='buttons'> 
                   <button class='button is-link'> 
                   Login 
                   </button> 
               </div> 
               </div> 
           </form> 
           </div> 
       </div> 
       <button class="modal-close is-large"
               aria-label="close"> 
           Model 
       </button> 
       </div> 
   </div> 
   </div> 
</div> 

<script> 
   const modal = document.querySelector('.modal'); 
   const btn = document.querySelector('#btn') 
   const close = document.querySelector('.modal-close') 

   btn.addEventListener('click', 
                       function () { 
   modal.style.display = 'block' 
   }) 

   close.addEventListener('click', 
                       function () { 
   modal.style.display = 'none' 
   }) 

   window.addEventListener('click', 
                           function (event) { 
   if (event.target.className === 
       'modal-background') { 
       modal.style.display = 'none' 
   } 
   }) 
</script> 
</body>
```

Comment: You basically need to get some React basics down so you would know how to add event listeners, I would recommend watching for YouTube videos or get udemy course

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would add the `onClick` attribute to the element and call a function - `onClick={handleClick}`. So you can do this

```
btn.onClick = function () { 
  modal.style.display = 'block'
}
```

which sets the elements `onClick` attribute.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'onClick' of null

Comment: How are you linking your jsx and html. If you are using a script tag make sure it is at the bottom of the page before the `</body>` tag.